# Android stop waiting for debugger

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I have created an application using Eclipse and when connected to my Deivce i select run.  It waits for the debugger to attach then starts off fine.

My Question is, when i do not have the device attahced to my PC i can still see my application in the app list but when i select it i am still presented with the "waiting for debugger to attach" message.  My device as i said is not connected to my pc at this time.

I assumed since the app is in my list the apk is installed on my deivce itself so how do i get it to stop trying to debug the app ( when not connected to the PC ) and just run it !

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to run the app without debugger before unplugging your device?

Answer (score 5):

The reason is more than one Eclipse is running on your computer. On windows press Ctrl+Shift+Esc and kill all Eclipse and javaw instances. This will definetly solve the problem.

Comment: Using Ubuntu, I killed all `eclipse` and `java` instances. I had previously killed all eclipse instances, so maybe killing the java ones is the key.

Answer (score 1):

Some devices will only let the debugger attach if the application has the `android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP` permission set in its manifest file:

```
<manifest>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. What worked for me was restart of the device.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to connect your phone with the debugger, then uncheck the "wait-for-debugger"-option in your device under "developer options". This works for newer android versions (4.2.2).

In older android version you can uncheck the "USB Debugging"-option also under "developer options".

Answer (score -1):

I think you have

```
Debug.waitForDebugger();
```

method call somewhere in your code and hence the app is waiting to be connected to the debugger and it never runs further.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html#waitForDebugger()

Answer (score -2):

Set debug mood off or false from your application androidmanifest.xml

```
<application 
    android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:debuggable="true">
```

Comment: He wants to debug the application and you say him to set debuggable false. -1 for this.